# Unable to browse even when connected to free WiFi

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat, samsung

I am unable to browse the internet, even if my phone is connected to my office free WiFi.

I have tried resetting my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to some other WiFi source and recheck. Your office WiFI puts some restrictions like only specific MAC IDs can browse. In that case your device will get connected, however will lack in internet.

Also, check if there is a proxy or firewall in ur office that blocks your phone.